# iis7 increase number of threads/concurrent requests per working process

Tags: performance, iis-7, multithreading, request

How can I increase the number of threads/concurrent requests per working process on IIS7?

I don't want to increase the number of processes to create a web garden (for now).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found it:

```
 <system.web>
        <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="12" maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" requestQueueLimit="5000"/>
 </system.web>
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560842(VS.100).aspx

Comment: This setting must be added to aspnet.config file, not the web.config file.

Comment: I must add that this does set the number of concurrent requests handled by ASP.NET, but does not affect the number of concurrent requests handled by IIS (like static files). Also, 5000 is the default maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU from .NET 4.0. 12 was the default in 2.0.

Comment: @ChristianDavén if this suggested answer does not actually increase the number of requests handled by IIS, do you know how to increase it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://iistuner.codeplex.com/ it solved all of our problems regarding setting these numbers. It basically fixes all wierd and hard to find settings with one click.