# Increase number of threads per worker process IIS

Tags: iis-7, worker-process

How do you increase the number of threads per worker process in IIS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iis7 increase number of threads/concurrent requests per working process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293865/iis7-increase-number-of-threads-concurrent-requests-per-working-process)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, oh yes, however they dont have the UI way of setting the IIS. So I thought this would be helpful.

Comment: you can always answer the question with your answer instead of a creating a new question and answer; it just gets confusing when there are multiple questions asking the same thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using IIS this can be done. I searched everywhere, so I decided to put this out here for everyone to use this information.

Click on the server. Then on the right side pane, double click on ASP.
[image: Features view - ASP]

Increase the number of threads per processor
[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to affect non-ASP applications. Does anyone know how to do this for ISAPI applications? http://serverfault.com/questions/531775/how-do-i-reduce-the-threads-per-process-limit-for-an-isapi-app-under-iis-7-5

Comment: This doesn't even apply to ASP.NET, it is related to just plain old ASP without .NET.

Comment: looks like it works for ASP.NET from IIS 7.0 onwards : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Using config files

For example:

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64[version]\config\machine.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <connectionManagement>
            <add address="*" maxconnection="24" />
        </connectionManagement>
    </system.net>
    <system.web>
        <processModel
            autoConfig="true"
            maxWorkerThreads = "100"
            maxIoThreads = "100"
            minWorkerThreads = "50"
            minIoThreads = "50" />
        <httpRuntime 
            minFreeThreads="176" 
            minLocalRequestFreeThreads="152" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can this be overriden at the web.config level for a site?

Answer (score -11):

In `Application Pool` > `Advanced Settings` > `Maximum Worker Processes`

Comment: This way you set number of processes, not number of threads per process.