# Setting MinThreads in ThreadPool

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, threadpool, stackexchange.redis

I have faced the time out issue in the StackExchange.Redis. And the exception is like below.

> Timeout performing GET CacheXXXX, inst: 18, mgr: Inactive, err: never,
>   queue: 44, qu: 0, qs: 44, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 65536, ar: 0,
>   clientName: XXXXX, serverEndpoint:
>   Unspecified/XXXXX.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, keyHashSlot: 1612,
>   IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=39,Free=8152,Min=8,Max=8191) (Please take a look at this article
>   for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:
>   http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

I'm trying to change the min threads in ThreadPool as below in **application start** (global.asax)

```
 protected void Application_Start()
       {
           int minWorker, minIOC;
           ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out minWorker, out minIOC);
           minWorker = 200;
           ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(minWorker, minIOC);
       }
```

So i changed the  **Worker** threads to resolve this error.
But below is the exception :

> Timeout performing GET CacheABCD, inst:
>   0, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 5, qu: 4, qs: 1, qc: 0, wr: 1,
>   wq: 1, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: XXXXX, serverEndpoint:
>   Unspecified/XXXXX.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, keyHashSlot:
>   13995, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=800,Min=400,Max=800), WORKER:
>   (Busy=31,Free=769,Min=8,Max=800) (Please take a look at this article
>   for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:
>   http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

In the above code i have changed only Worker threads. But **IOCP** is changed, **Worker** threads is not changed.

Please help.

Comment: It might be a good idea to check if any limitations from OS, e.g. [ThreadPool.SetMinThreads doesn't work in IIS hosted application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549717/threadpool-setminthreads-doesnt-work-in-iis-hosted-application)