Asynchronous Fetch in Javascript
I need to make a call to a file named chiamata_preventivo.php, which takes about 10 minutes to respond. While this page is being processed, I would like to open a new tab to dashboard.php to allow the user to navigate while the request is being processed. The issue is that the call is blocking, and I'm unable to make it work with fetch() or an AJAX call.
Main file (this script is in the HTML head):
<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('chiamata_preventivo.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ datiJson: <?php echo $json; ?> })
                });
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log(data);

                // Open the dashboard in a new tab
                window.open("../../common_page/dashboard.php", "_blank");
            } catch (error) {
                alert('Error in request: ' + error);
            }
        });
    </script>

chiamata_preventivo.php
<?php
$_pageProfile = "*";
$nome_pagina = "chiamata_preventivo.php";

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/common/database_connect.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/interfacce/bartolini/richiesta_bartolini.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json');

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $dati = json_decode($input, true);
    $json = $dati["datiJson"];

    $response = dispatchRequestRCA(json_encode($json));
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
?>

Any solutions?

What does "blocking" mean? Is there a specific error message you'd like to tell us about?

The execution of the call does not allow me to open other pages or perform other actions.

Ajax is asynchronous so it won't block the browser. But conceivably it might stop your webserver from responding to other requests. Consider executing long-running jobs as background tasks and having a mechanism to notify the user when they are complete, rather than having it consume webserver resources for such a long time

@kevinpcf remove the await to make it non-blocking

@ArunAS await doesn't block. Just yields to the execution thread and resumes when the awaited value resolves.

AJAX is blocking my web server too. I'm calling an API, do you know any solutions to handle this task in the background?

"While this page is being processed, I would like to open a new tab to dashboard.php" why not just move the window.open(); to before the await fetch()?

I already tried but not working

Cron can run background jobs. Or there are other systems you can research.

@ADyson problem with cron is finding out when it ran and when it finished. It's been quit a while since I wrote PHP - back when I last did (2011) there was no native way to launch separate processes. But you could use a fork() system command to try and do it manually. Not a very pretty solution, since you have to care about properly ending child processes and such. Also, servers might be configured try and kill or limit longer running processes. Don't know the landscape today. But I at least expect there are other tools that make this less of a PIA. At any rate, that's a separate question.

@VLAZ the job would have to notify the front end somehow when it finishes a task. E.g. by writing to a websocket maybe. Or setting a status which a user can periodically check. Or sending an email. Lots of possibilities.  Not sure why you think launching a separate process would be needed btw?

@ADyson just sharing my (quite old) experience with PHP. But yes, the job can do something. maybe even write to a file that the application monitors. Lots of possibilities, honestly. Just nothing to concretely pick here, since there is hardly enough information to make an well-informed decision.

The popup blockers in modern browsers won't let you open another window automatically, without any relevant user interaction (i.e., a click on a link, button or something.) Since you are invoking the whole thing via the DOMContentLoaded event, you won't be able to open a new window from there, no matter if you place the window.open calls inside the AJAX request, or before.

What web server are you using?

If your other PHP pages are waiting for that script to finish, check for any session usage - namely session_start and session_write_close. A lot of people's first apps will simply open the session immediately, then close it at the end - this causes blocking. Instead you should only open the session as needed, then close asap.

I'm using IIS as Web Server

@kevinpcf If this is a server issue you need to look into how IIS is handling requests. Maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599939/increase-number-of-threads-per-worker-process-iis or this guide: https://www.leansentry.com/guide/iis-aspnet-hangs/iis-thread-pool

Okay so there is a way to resolve this but its a bad idea.
Let me start with how to fix it... Then Ill explain why the "fix" is a bad idea.
in your chiamata_preventivo.php file you will need to add at the top of the file.
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
ini_set('max_input_time', '-1');

This basically lets php run as long as needed and allows it to take up as much  memory as needed. There are times when browsers need to run a process longer than the standard timeout (usually 30 seconds).
Now heres why this is a BAD idea:
Not only is it bad UX to make a user watch a spinner for 10 minutes, there are security risks to leaving a connection open that long.
If you have to change the memory limit, that means you have a memory leak, and/or you're trying to execute something in the browser that should be done via exec or shell_exec
That being said, controlling the memory limit and execution time from your php controller should allow the ajax request to not get "blocked" (the real term is "timeout")
Please do not use my solution. But if you do, it will "fix" your issue.

The await will pause the execution:

await is usually used to unwrap promises by passing a Promise as the expression. Using await pauses the execution of its surrounding async function until the promise is settled (that is, fulfilled or rejected). When execution resumes, the value of the await expression becomes that of the fulfilled promise. (await | MDN)

Therefor the code after your fetch request only run after the fetch request promise has returned.
You can call the fetch function without the await and then use Promise.prototype.then() to do stuff when the promise of the request is returned.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  fetch('data:application/json,{"status":"OK"}', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      datiJson: 'test'
    })
  }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
  // Open the dashboard in a new tab
  // but not functional on stackoverflow
  //window.open("../../common_page/dashboard.php", "_blank");
  console.log('call the window.open function');
});




The problem is the server being blocked, not the client. Read the comments
